# Using VBA to consume WCF web service, how to change binding?

Tags: ms-access, wcf, soap, vba

I am working on an Access 2010 'tool' that will hopefully allow me to sync our local Access database with an online one (hosted on a server that we have zero control over or direct access to).  My background is not in VBA or VB.net so I am fairly new to this language so any help or suggestions would be appreciated.  So far this is what I have written as a test to verify the ability to connect and to better understand what is returned when we do get a valid response.

```
Public Sub SendXML()
    Dim myHTTP As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    Dim myDom As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim myXML As String
    Set myHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    Set myDom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    myDom.async = False
    myXML = "<s:Envelope xmlns:a=" & Chr(34) & "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" & Chr(34) & "xmlns:s=" & Chr(34) & "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" & Chr(34) & "><s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand=" & Chr(34) & "1" & Chr(34) & ">http://tempuri.org/IWcfService/Get_InitiativeList_CSV</a:Action></s:Header><s:Body><Get_InitiativeList_CSV xmlns=" & Chr(34) & "http://tempuri.org/" & Chr(34) & "><userID>MYUSERID</userID></Get_InitiativeList_CSV></s:Body></s:Envelope>"
    myDom.LoadXML (myXML)
    myHTTP.Open "post", "https://server/WcfService/WcfService.svc", False
    myHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"   
    'myHTTP.send (myDom.XML)
    myHTTP.send (myXML)
    MsgBox myHTTP.responseText
End Sub
```

I get back:

```
The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported.
```

A couple things to note above.  I tried two different way to create the XML string.  One creating it as you see above and sending that raw text to the server. And creating the string as you see above and using `loadXML` to create the string. I do not know why one would be better than the other but both returned the same error.

Now, I have tried SOA Cleaner Express and am able to connect successfully to the service and get data back.  Since SOA Cleaner is able to connect I figured using the RAW SOAP/XML string SOA sends in VBA might be a good starting point. I noticed that using SOA cleaner it has a WCF Binding as `WsHttpBinding` and if I change this binding to `BasicHttpBinding`I get a similar error message as I am getting in VBA, to be exact:

```
Content Type text/xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service
```

Not even sure I am going in the right direction, but if I am, how do I set or change the 'binding' in VBA?  Is there something else going on here? I am sure it is something simple, but like I said I do not have a VBA background, and WCF and SOAP are somewhat new to me as well.

I appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, the binding from the client must match the service, so if the service only supports `wsHttpBinding`, the client must use that as well.

For added flexiblity calling a WCF service from VBA, including the ability to specify the binding, you may want to use monikers instead. Here is an example of service monkier being constructed and used in VBA:

```
Dim addr As String
addr = "service:mexAddress=""net.tcp://localhost:7891/Test/WcfService1/Service1/Mex"","
addr = addr + "address=""net.tcp://localhost:7891/Test/WcfService1/Service1/"","
addr = addr + "contract=""IService1"", contractNamespace=""http://tempuri.org/"","
addr = addr + "binding=""NetTcpBinding_IService1"", bindingNamespace=""http://tempuri.org/"""

Dim service1 As Object
Set service1 = GetObject(addr)

MsgBox service1.GetData(12)
```

Here are some links with more info, including the source of this code snippet:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752245(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752245%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
http://damianblog.com/2009/07/05/excel-wcf/

Comment: Thank you for responding and the links.  I have visited both and very quickly got lost.  I am needing a bit more information to get started.   First, from a quick google, I do not think the service I am trying to consume has a 'MexAddress', nor do I know or understand what a MexAddress is.  The package I post to the service is formatted in SOAP (if that helps).

Comment: Indeed, SOAP is the default protocol for WCF. Can you get a WSDL for the service to describe it? (add "?WSDL" to the end of the service URL in a browser). How do you know what operations are available on the service?

Comment: Yes, I can get the WSDL via the browser.  I have also used SOA Cleaner Pro to load the WSDL and get the specific operations.  I also have a technical doc that describes the operations (what is expected in and what is returned).

Answer (score 0):

This may be far-fetched, but given that the second error is more descriptive than the first error, have you tried specifying the charset?

```
myHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8"
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately adding `charset=utf-8 results` in the same error message.